# Passing mongodb queries through REST API in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am building a REST API to MongoDB using Flask-RESTful. One feature request I have received is to be able to pass arbitrarily complex Mongo queries, e.g. JSON docs, through the API. I am a little concerned about the implementation here. At first, I would just make a new endpoint (`users/query/<json>`). I was looking at other implementations, where it was passed through as a parameter (`users/query?q={}`). Now my questions are:

What is the preferred method?

Is this even a good idea?

Am I missing something?

Thanks!